# Github pages doesn't show my images with an Angular deploy

Tags: angular, github, github-pages

I already finish a page in localhost, everything works fine but, when I deploy my app using `angular-cli-ghpages` in fact it deploys but my pictures don't. My Angular project root is like this:
[Proyect structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qI8iR.png).
And my pictures are store in a folder inside assets.

Also, you can check structure from my repository: [repo](https://github.com/NotAUserName0/Portafolio)
And my page is like this: [page](https://notausername0.github.io/Portafolio/)

In the past I've already try this and it works fine, but now I don't know what is wrong.

I try to change my `<img src="">` source using the url from github, using relative urls, I also try to change the url in the github code page, searching on internet I saw that using this `ng build --prod` helps but it sends me an error that --prod doesn't exist. Nothing work and I don't know what else to do.